# Don't understand why this code work's in one istance but not the other

Tags: javascript

I have many drop down boxes on a form in Bluebeam extreme. I am very novice with both Bluebeam and Java but found code that will populate the drop down and a textbox that displays the corresponding phone number. Works great for 3 of the 4 drop downs on the form the 4th one just won't load.

I have double checked all the names of the boxes and all are correct, the only difference between the other 3 is the one that doesn't work contains 11 names where the other 3 are less than 10

```
var contarr = new Array() ;
contarr[0] = ["Estimator", "Telephone"] ;
contarr[1] = ["Adam Pope", "(916) 343-0113"]
contarr[2] =  [“Arnold Petter", "(916) 439-7587"]
contarr[3] =  ["Austin Phillips", "(916) 343-0008"]
contarr[4] =  ["Bryan Lluen", "(916) 660-6336"]
contarr[5] =  ["Cecil Jaquess", "(916) 275-0739"]
contarr[6] =  ["Dave Pope", "(916) 997-2568"]
contarr[7] =  ["Geoff Glines", "(775) 745-5020"]
contarr[8] =  ["Josh Hinckley", "(775) 225-3690"]
contarr[9] =  ["Joshua Narker", "(916) 343-2534"]
contarr[10] =  ["Maria Solis", "(916) 343-2568"]
contarr[11] =  ["Matt Wood", "(916) 969-9075"]

var names = [];
for (var i = 0; i < contarr.length; i++) {
    names.push(contarr[i][0]);
}

this.getField("Est").setItems(names);
this.getField("Est").setAction("Keystroke", "onContactSwitch(event.value);");

selectContact(0);   // Choose initial contact

function onContactSwitch(name) {
    for (var i = 0; i < contarr.length; i++) {
        if (contarr[i][0] == name) {
            selectContact(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}

function selectContact(i) {

    this.getField("EstimatorPhone").value = contarr[i][1];
}
```

I get no error just the drop down box is empty when selected

Comment: There is a non-standard quote (a curly quote `“` instead of a regular quote `"`) before the name `Arnold Petter` that may be causing issues.

Comment: What is `this.getField`? Top-level code shouldn't generally use `this`, it should only be used in functions.

Comment: Not sure it was code i found on the internet. what should the syntax be

Comment: Worthwelle that was it. i don't think i would have ever noticed that thanks a ton!